# Weird issue with cfpdfform in Coldfusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a weird issue with some (but not all) of my CF servers.

I upgraded the OS on my CF servers from CentOS 5 to CentOS 6. I also upgraded from CF 8 to 10. All the hosts are configured the same (deployed using puppet) and are on the same patch level for CF 10. 2 of 3 servers are working fine when we call the cfpdfform tag. There is one server, however, that is failing to generate pdfs. I get the following error in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 52; Attribute name "xml:xml" associated with an element type "xfdf" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

I know there is some [issue with cfpdform on CF10](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3430402) that we need to address, but I'm trying to figure out why/how the exact same code is working without issue/error on the other 2 hosts.

EDIT: Adding code generating error and stack trace (with removed paths for obvious privacy reasons

STACK TRACE:

```
coldfusion.pdf.PDFFormException: An exception has occured in the processing of PDF forms.
    at coldfusion.pdf.XFDFDataXMLGenerator.createFormXMLData(XFDFDataXMLGenerator.java:119)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.PDFFormTag.doEndTag(PDFFormTag.java:328)
    at cf_cardholderAgreementPDFForm2ecfm1614851083._factor10(/path/to/code/PDFForm.cfm:30)
    at cf_cardholderAgreementPDFForm2ecfm1614851083.runPage(/path/to/code/PDFForm.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2799)
    at cfcardholderAgreement_BIN2ecfm1678891588.runPage(/path/to/code/Agreement_BIN.cfm:76)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2799)
    at cf_cardholderAgreement2ecfm1711879224.runPage(/path/to/code/Agreement.cfm:88)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2799)
    at cfcardholder_agreement2ecfm1781672563.runPage(/path/to/code/agreement.cfm:2)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2799)
    at cfcontroller2ecfm174429127._factor1(/path/to/code/controller.cfm:240)
    at cfcontroller2ecfm174429127._factor2(/path/to/code/controller.cfm:212)
    at cfcontroller2ecfm174429127._factor3(/path/to/code/controller.cfm:1)
    at cfcontroller2ecfm174429127.runPage(/path/to/code/controller.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2799)
    at cfindex2ecfm2051298971.runPage(/path/to/code/index.cfm:2)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2799)
    at cfApplication2ecfc808894159$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(/path/to/code/Application.cfc:148)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:655)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:444)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:414)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:108)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:300)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:424)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:204)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: Attribute name "xml:xml" associated with an element type "xfdf" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:533)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:946)
    at coldfusion.pdf.XFDFDataXMLGenerator.createFormXMLData(XFDFDataXMLGenerator.java:84)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 52; Attribute name "xml:xml" associated with an element type "xfdf" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
Attribute name "xml:xml" associated with an element type "xfdf" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

SOURCE:

```
<cfpdfform source="#pdfFormSource#" action="populate" destination="#pdfFormDestination#" overwrite="yes">
    ...
    <cfpdfformparam name="websiteLogIn"             value="#websiteLogIn#">
    ...
</cfpdfform>
```

Comment: Is there more to the stack trace?  Have you tried clearing all the caches-- template cache, etc?

Comment: CF10 is not supported on CentOS. However, you can continue using it.

Please share the piece of code failing and the stack trace from exception.log

Comment: Also have you searched the bug db? Your issue sounds similar to [Bug #3430402](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3430402)?

Comment: @Leigh , we were aware of that bug and as soon as we could schedule a release of the code, we were intending on adding the fdf=true flag. What's I'm trying to figure out is why this is working on 2/3 servers without any modification to the code.

Comment: @BradWood - Cleared caches. No joy.

Comment: My bad, I missed your earlier comment about that. Obviously my coffee has not kicked in yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this answer is going to be useless to anyone else, but it worked for me.

The host is on a VMWare cluster. Reinstalling the OS didn't help. After much frustration and debating with my developers, I decided to remove and recreate the VM to remove that as a variable. Sure enough, that worked. I have no idea why. The VM was setup the same way. But it worked.

If anyone else is experiencing the same issue, try that.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to be similar to the following:

[Odd error from ColdFusion when building a PDF with CFPDFFORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498792/)

No solution given, but see if their work-around works for you too, in the meantime.

And as @Leigh already mentioned, there's a bug report for this at [adobe.com#3430402](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3430402):

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments to @Leigh, I am aware of the bug report and that we need to edit the code for this to work. As I also pointed out, the purpose of this question is to figure out why this is working fine on 2 servers and not working on 1.